# Using ggvis to plot multiple lines with error bars in R

Tags: r, plot, graph, ggvis

I want to make a line with points in `ggvis`. I used the [cookbook located here](http://ggvis.rstudio.com/cookbook.html)

My question: I want to plot another line in a different color on top of this graph using different data. Also, I want to plot little error bars above and below each point for both lines that will correspond to some vectors that I have with IQR or SD data. Any ideas?

```
library(ggvis)
data(pressure)
```

Lines with points:

```
pressure %>% ggvis(~temperature, ~pressure) %>%
  layer_points() %>% 
  layer_lines()
```

Answer (score 1):

I can answer your first question: how to plot another line in a different color on top of the first graph using different data. I have not yet found a solution for error bars in ggvis.

You can use the 'data =' argument when you define the various layers as in the example at the very bottom of this page:
http://ggvis.rstudio.com/data-hierarchy.html

Define some datasets:

```
bend <- data.frame("Date" = seq(as.Date("2014-01-01"), as.Date("2014-01-31"), by = 1), 
               "PM25" = c(12.2, 3.5,  3.6, 12.5, 10.8,  9.0,  2.4,  1.5,  1.7,  1.7,
                          1.5,  1.4,  5.1,  6.1, 10.2, 10.9, 10.4, 10.4, 11.4, 12.7,
                          17.9, 5.9,  4.2, 11.8, 16.8,  5.8,  7.0,  9.6,  1.5,  5.4,  5.7))
albany <- data.frame("Date" = seq(as.Date("2014-01-01"), as.Date("2014-01-31"), by = 1), 
                 "PM25" = c(6.5, 5.7, 6.3, 11.4,  3.8,  5.9,  6.5,  3.1,  7.7,  6.7,
                            5.5,  7.2,  4.3, 11.2, 10.4, 10.0,  7.7, 13.2,  7.7, 19.9,
                            12.6, 8.6, 5.7, 8.4,  6.9, 15.7, 15.2, 16.2, 13.1, 11.3,  0.7))
```

Make the graph:

```
ggvis(data = NULL, x = ~Date, y = ~PM25) %>%
layer_points(fill := "red", data = bend) %>%
layer_paths(stroke := "red", data = bend) %>%
layer_points(fill := "blue", data = albany) %>%
layer_paths(stroke := "blue", data = albany) %>%
add_axis("x", format = "%Y-%b-%d",  
       tick_padding = 30, title_offset = 80,
       properties = axis_props(
         labels = list(angle = 270)))
```

Unfortunately, the data= argument is not currently working with layer_lines (see here: https://github.com/rstudio/ggvis/issues/440), but it is working with layer_paths.